# Makefile for plugins compilation

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I have this simple structure:

```
.
test.c
plugins/a.c
plugins/b.c
plugins/c.c
```

And I'm compiling this with a bash script:

```
gcc -o test test.c -std=gnu99 -ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic

gcc -c plugins/a.c -o plugins/a.o -pedantic -g -Wall -std=c99 -fpic -I.
gcc plugins/a.o -o plugins/a.so  -shared

...same for b and c...
```

Anyways, I want to port that to a Makefile. Here's what I have:

```
CC          =   gcc

PLUGIN_DIR  =   plugins
PLUGINS_C   =   $(wildcard $(PLUGIN_DIR)/*.c)
PLUGINS_O   =   $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(PLUGINS_C))

new: clean all

all: test plugins

test: test.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -std=gnu99 -ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic

plugins:
    ???

$(PLUGIN_DIR)/*.c:
    $(CC) -c $(PLUGIN_DIR)/$@ $^ -pedantic -g -Wall -std=c99 -fpic -I.

$(PLUGIN_DIR)/*.o:
    $(CC) $@ $^ -shared

clean:
    rm -rf test *.o *.a plugins/*.o plugins/*.so
```

But this won't work as the `plugins` rule is empty and I really can't find out what should I write in there to make it compile all the plugins inside the `plugins` folder.
Also, I'm not sure if I messed up things with `$@` and `$^`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your makefile before we get to your question.

The wildcard character in a rule target is <kbd>%</kbd> not <kbd>*</kbd> (in lines like your `$(PLUGIN_DIR)/*.c:`).

Rules specify how the files named by the target/target pattern are built. So your `%.c` rule is telling make how to build .c files (which I trust you'll agree) isn't exactly what you meant. (Similarly your `%.o` rule is telling make how to build .o files).

You don't have any prerequisites (right-hand side of <kbd>:</kbd> in a target line) listed for your build rules so make cannot intelligently rebuild targets as their prerequisites are changed (and will never rebuild them instead).

To get to your question, you likely don't want anything in the body of the plugins target. Instead you want to list the desired plugins output files (the .so files) as the prerequisites of the `plugins` target. (You will also want to include `.PHONY: plugins` in your makefile to tell make that `plugins` is not a real file but instead a phony target.)

Your `%.so` rule wants to be more like:

```
$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.so: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o
        $(CC) $^ -o $@ -shared
```

and your `%.o` rule wants to be more like:

```
$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.c
        $(CC) -c $< -o $@ -pedantic -g -Wall -std=c99 -fpic -I.
```

Comment: But I do want to tell how Makefile should compile my files inside the ```plugins``` dir. Isn't exactly that what the ```$(PLUGIN_DIR)/%.c:``` rule is doing? How about this: http://pastebin.com/tVSYSTUq ?

Comment: `$(PLUGIN_DIR)/%.c:` says "make if you need to know how to *create* a file that matches this pattern here are the rules for you to use to do so". But that's not what the rule is doing. The rule is using an *existing* .c file to *create* and matching .o file. So your target pattern needs to indicate that. Try adding prerequisite entries to your rules to see what I mean (look at your `test: test.o` rule as an example.

Comment: The makefile at that link is better. It has reasonable prerequisites for the `plugins` target (though you don'y really need to include `$(PLUGINS_C)` in the prerequisites list since they should by prerequisites of the files in `$(PLUGINS_O)` (they aren't currently) and so shouldn't need to be listed there specifically).

Comment: You also don't need the `plugins` target at all since you can put `$(PLUGINS_O)` as a prerequisite of the `all` target directly if you wanted to.

Comment: Better. But your %.c and %.o rules are still backwards. The file that matches the pattern of the target is the file that the command will create (and the file that `$@` expands to). What type of files does the `$(CC) -c $(PLUGINS_DIR)/$@ $^ -pedantic -g -Wall -std=c99 -fpic -I.` command create? What about `$(CC) -o $@ $^ -std=gnu99 -ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic`? Compare the files they generate against the targets they are rules for. Also (as an additional hint/nudge in the right direction) where do you tell make to generate the .so file from the .o files?

Comment: I'm getting closer (thanks to you!). Now I have this: http://pastebin.com/krZkLnpW which does work with 1 file in the ```plugins``` folder, but as soon as I add a second file, it fails. I attached the output of ```make V=1```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40918/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-alexandernst)

Comment: One more comment. You might want to use `$(PLUGINS_O)` and `$(PLUGINS_SO)` instead of wildcards in your clean rule. That way it matches with what make expects to build and won't delete unrelated files.